# Where is the function that generates the scroll bar in Dark Reader?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have been looking through the source code of Dark Reader extension.
https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader
I can't find the code or function that is responsible for generating the dark scroll bar on the right side of web pages. In which file is it located? There are a ton of .ts files.

Comment: I guess it will be faster if you ask this question directly on darkreader issue.

Comment: Why do you assume it is in TypeScript? [This search](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader/search?q=-webkit-scrollbar&unscoped_q=-webkit-scrollbar) might be... illuminating? Especially the bit in `src/ui/shared.less`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm trying to make the dark scroll bar appear universally on all websites, even when the dark mode is off.

Comment: There are tons of `::-webkit-scrollbar` CSS selectors to customize various parts of the scrollbars. I think there should be existing answers about that. You can declare a content script `css` to add to all [matching] pages, see the documentation. An example of advanced scrollbar customization I saw recently: [userstyle](https://userstyles.org/styles/142097/) (click "Show CSS code" and find the selector I gave).

Answer (score 2):

The function for changing default scrollbar color is located in [src/inject/dynamic-theme/modify-css.ts](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader/blob/master/src/inject/dynamic-theme/modify-css.ts) file. If website author's CSS changes the scrollbar color, such color will be processed as a background color. There is an ability to force scrollbar color via Dev Tools.